# Callback Example Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have following simple example to demonstrate callback function:

```
<script>
// The callback method
function meaningOfLife() {
    console.log("The meaning of life is: 42");
}

// A method which accepts a callback method as an argument
function printANumber(number, meaningOfLife) {
    console.log("The number you provided is: " + number);
}

// Driver method
printANumber(6, meaningOfLife);
</script>
```

**Expected Result**

```
The number you provided is 6
The meaning of life is: 42
```

**Real Result**

```
The number you provided is 6
```

> Why I am not getting the second line while running this example for callback function?

Comment: The printANumber function does not invoke the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printANumber` method accepts a callback as an argument, but never calls it (or does anything else with it).

Just passing a value to a function does nothing except populate the argument with that value.

If you want to use that value, then use it.

```
meaningOfLife();
```

This would be clearer if you didn't reuse variable names. You have two different variables both called `meaningOfLife`. Let's change that:

```
function printANumber(number, callback) {
    console.log("The number you provided is: " + number);
    callback();
}
```

Comment: But when we add a function in the end of another function, it must run it after completing its task. This is called "callback" I hope. So after printing first line it must go to the meaningOfLife() function. Isnt it?

Comment: Even if I make changes nothing happens. The second line does not populate.

Comment: "But when we add a function in the end of another function"  — This sentence doesn't make sense. You don't "add" functions, you can call them or pass them as arguments or convert them to strings or various other things. "Adding" is not one of them, they are not numbers.

Comment: "This is called "callback" I hope." — There is nothing called "callback" in your code. You have a global variable called `meaningOfLife` which is a function, and you have an argument called `meaningOfLife` which you don't pass a value to and don't do anything with. (At least you didn't before your edit)

Comment: I have passed it as argument but still I am only getting first line printed, not second!

Comment: @Peterson — You still aren't doing anything with the value of the argument. You have to call the function in order for it to be called.

Comment: @Peterson: As the answer says: you passed it as an argument to `printANumber`, but `printANumber` didn't do anything with that argument.

Comment: @Ryan: But that is the idea; I dont want to specifically call the meaningOfLife(); It must be called automatically once the first line is printed.

Comment: @Peterson — It would be less confusing if your argument had a different name from the global. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer. You **must** still call the function in order for it to be called. Just passing a function as an argument won't do anything. It wouldn't make sense for it to do anything.

Comment: @Peterson I think you are confused about what a callback means in this context. It is just a function in a variable, which you must call in your code.

Comment: Yes, I thought that its magic that without calling it again specifically, browser automatically runs it because its function and last argument. If I have to call it specifically then there's no magic! It is common sense it is called so it would run! I thought of some extra flavor .... in callback.

Comment: Functions run when you run them (and you may "just run them" (with or without arguments of their own) or you might use `apply` or `call` or `bind` (and then pass them to something else) or `new` or set properties on them (functions are objects too). They don't run just because you pass them as arguments. Passing them as arguments *just* passes them as arguments. `addEventListener("click", someFunction)` would be bloody stupid if `someFunction` was called immediately and not when there was a click.

Comment: @Peterson You could wrap the function and the callback in another function to do it. Example: http://pastebin.com/evmWHDaQ. Works with multiple arguments, the last argument is always callback.

Answer (score 1):

If your `printANumber` function is going to accept a callback function as an argument, then you need to actually call/invoke/execute the callback.  The callback does not automatically get executed just because it was passed as an argument to your `printANumber` function.  Passing something as an argument populates the parameter variable within your function, but it does not inherently do anything with it.

To execute the callback, you can do something like:

```js
// The callback method
function meaningOfLife() {
    console.log("The meaning of life is: 42");
}

// A method which accepts a callback method as an argument
function printANumber(number, callback) {
    console.log("The number you provided is: " + number);
    //Verify that what was passed as 'callback' is actually a function
    if (typeof callback === 'function'){
        callback(); //Actually execute the callback function
    }
}

// Driver method
printANumber(6, meaningOfLife);
```